# Update a library field when uploading a file using javascript

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, spfx-webparts, file-upload

I am using a spfx webpart to upload a file and modified a column value associated tothat file. The code below works and stop working without any reason and i can modify only the title field with it. I had check all proper internal names for the other fields but it doesn't work. i don't get any error.

```
const payload={Title:test};
 web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(_parent.props.listName)
      .files.add(file.name, file, true)
      .then(({ file }) => file.getItem())
      .then(item => item.update(payload))
      .then(console.log)
      .catch(console.error);
    }
```